# Retrieve single record with recent date from a table having same column value in multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table with data as below:

```
LabId   lab_name  Measured_date value
------  --------  ------------- -----
1519253 LAST_DBP   19-JUN-12     78
1519252 LAST_SBP   19-JUN-12     151
1519267 LDL        27-AUG-12     84
1519262 LDL        17-AUG-12     86
1519250 SBP        17-AUG-12     181
```

I wanted to retrieve data from this table such that, if more than one record exists for same lab_name I would need the record with latest measured_date. So my desired output should look like:

```
LabId   lab_name  Measured_date value
------  --------  ------------- -----
1519253 LAST_DBP   19-JUN-12     78
1519252 LAST_SBP   19-JUN-12     151
1519267 LDL        27-AUG-12     84
1519250 SBP        17-AUG-12     181
```

Thanks
Gopi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Analytic fn: Rank()

```
   WITH TEMP AS
    (
    SELECT LabId ,  lab_name ,Measured_date ,value,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY lab_name  ORDER BY Measured_date desc) AS RK
    FROM TABLE1
    )
    SELECT LabId ,  lab_name ,Measured_date ,value FROM TEMP WHERE RK=1;
```